# Make new GIT repository

Tags: git, initialization

I'm trying to make a new git repository on my server performing the following steps one after another:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m 'Initial Commit'
git push -u origin master
```

I'm always getting the issue:

> error: src refspec master does not match any.
>
> error: failed to push some refs to 'origin'

What am I doing wrong? How to get a clean new repository?

**UPDATE:**

I tried to add a file to the folder afterwards and performing the steps mentioned above again, except the `git init` getting the issue:

> fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
>
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
> and the repository exists.

This happens also if I perform all the steps above on a none empty directory.

I am working on user root, so rights shouldn't be the problem on this, or am I wrong? Does git run on a different user than I am performing the steps on?

Comment: Run `git branch` and see what branches you have. What does this tell you about pushing your `master` branch?

Comment: `git branch` doesn't return anything. But I guess it should on a new repo.

Comment: After the update I am getting a `* master` on `git branch`

Comment: You don't need to run `git push -u origin master` .You would need to clone your repo to another folder or another machine - that's the place where you run `git push -u origin master` to push the commits back to your initial repository.

Comment: @LUXS: Right. Either your `git commit` failed, or you never actually ran `git commit`, so you never had any commits *in* the repository and no branch named `master` that you could use to push the commits you did not have anyway. When you retried these you *did* get at least one commit, and a branch named `master` to refer to it. I'm not sure whose instructions you are following here, but there's definitely something not right about them.

Answer (score 1):

In your steps, you never defined `origin` (which explain the "'`origin`' does not appear to be a git repository" error message)

So you need at least to add:

```
git remote add origin /url/of/remote/repo
```

That would be typically:

```
https://github.com/auser/anEmptyRepo
# or
git@github.com:auser/anEmptyRepo
```

> I am working on user `root`,

That is not a best practice: if possible, no-one should "work as `root`".

> so rights shouldn't be the problem on this, or am I wrong?

If by "rights" you are referring to the error message "Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.", it has nothing to do with the local user, and everything the credentials associated with the local user account: those credentials are necessary to prove the ownership of the repo you want to push to.

- For HTTPS, said credentials (remote repo hosting service login and password) can be cached by a [credential helper](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage) (`git config credential.helper`)
- For SSH, they are in `~root/.ssh/id_rsa[.pub]`

If those credentials are missing, you won't be able to push to a remote repo.

> Does git run on a different user than I am performing the steps on?

Git commands are executed with your current *local* user, but again, the credentials used to authenticate to the remote repo hosting service must be present/correct.

Answer (score 0):

Following that list of instructions without doing anything else, it is sure that you don't have a remote set up to push to. Try setting up a remote first and then try pushing to it.

Comment: You'd get a different error (namely: `fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository`) if the OP had actually done those steps. The conclusion is that the OP did something else. The `src refspec ... does not match` error message means there are no reference names that `master` can be mapped to, i.e., if there are branches, none of them are named `master`.

Comment: I rather think that the directory is empty and `git commit` didn't commit anything and didn't create branch `master`.

Comment: Since I am not yet performing any steps remote, I guess this answer is not promotional.